# Entity Framework 6 preventing deletion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

How do you make EF not allow deletion of a related entity? eg:

```
public class Enrollment 
{
    public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course 
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a Course A and B, and then I create an Enrollment and add those courses to it, I need it to not allow me to delete Courses A or B. When I run it through my MVC controller this has no problem:

```
Course course = db.Courses.Find(id);
db.Courses.Remove(course);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I'm not even sure exactly what to search for. I think it's enforcing or enabling a many to many referential constraint? But I don't seem to find anything. Am I supposed to not expect it to make that constraint automatically? I figured I could always add the following line to the Delete controller:

```
if(db.Enrollments.Any(e => e.Courses.Any(c => c.CourseId == id)))
{ //error }
```

Also, trying the following fluentAPI wasn't working (among many variations):

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>()
               .HasMany<Course>(e => e.Courses)
               .WithRequired()
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
               .HasMany(e => e.Enrollments);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Have a look into cascade deletes, possibly around `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);` in `OnModelCreating`. Your question is the opposite of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9752287/563532 - So you might have some luck there

Comment: Well, after trying all kinds of combinations, now I can't get update-database to succeed :(  I figured `modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().HasRequired(e => e.Courses).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);` but doesn't seem so.

Comment: I do think modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
               .HasMany(e => e.Enrollments); overrides your modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>()
               .HasMany<Course>(e => e.Courses)
               .WithRequired()
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); because they both configure the same relationship. delete the second line, and it should work. Oh, and insert the inverse navigation property.

Comment: Hmm.. I get error: `Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Courses_dbo.Enrollments_Enrollment_EnrollmentId". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.Enrollments", column 'EnrollmentId'.`  modelBuilder is: http://i.imgur.com/XgwCzA2.png and models are: http://i.imgur.com/FpM6siA.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you make EF not allow deletion of a related entity?

You want to prevent deleting things that is in used, right? Is course and enrollments a many to many relationship? Many to many will not cascade on delete by default. Try to change to this.

```
public class Enrollment 
{
    public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course 
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Need this to remove the cascade convention.
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
}
```

Comment: I thought it would prevent deletion by default as well. My actual models with all properties follow what you say and it doesn't work though: http://i.imgur.com/FpM6siA.png   currently I'm manually checking before course deletion if any enrollments use the course and if so redirecting.

Comment: Sorry, I remembered wrongly, the convention is they will cascade delete. Add `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();` to remove the convention. But this will remove cascade delete from all many to many relationship. Include this namespace for the convention. `using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;`