# How to remove rows for deleted fields from relationship table in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the `Student`, `Course` and a relationship between them as `StudentCourse`. The fields in these classes are as follows:

```
public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
        public Course Course { get; set; }
    }


public class Course
    {
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
    }



public class StudentCourse
    {   
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course {get;set;}
    }
```

When I delete the students in `student` table , then I want to remove the corresponding rows from the relationship `StudentClass`. How can I do  it?

Comment: @Slauma: Can you answer this please?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520418/entity-framework-code-first-delete-with-cascade

Comment: The model is strange. Don't you want a many-to-many relationship between `Student` and `Course`, i.e. a student can participate in *many* courses and a course can have *many* students? Normally you wouldn't need the `StudentCourse` entity because EF will manage the link table automatically. Can you explain why `Student` only has a single `Student.Course` reference and not a collection of courses?

Comment: @Slauma I am newbie to Entity Framework , Dont know what is wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you actually want a many-to-many relationship between `Student` and `Course`: A student can participate in *many* courses and a course can have *many* students.

In this case you can simplify your model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

The "join entity" `StudentCourse` is not needed. EF will create three tables from this model: A `Students` table, a `Courses` table and `StudentCourses` (or `CourseStudents`) table that will have a composite primary key `(StudentId, CourseId)` (or named similar). Both parts are foreign keys to their respective tables.

For the two FK relationships in the database *cascading delete* will be turned on by default. So, if a `Student` gets deleted the link records in the join table will be deleted automatically. The same when a `Course` gets deleted.

You can also define the detailed names for join table and join table columns explicity and you can also work with only a single collection, for example only the `Courses` collection in `Student` but without the `Students` collection in `Course`. You must use Fluent API for this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Courses)
    .WithMany() // no parameter if there is no collection in Course
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("StudentId");
        m.MapRightKey("CourseId");
        m.ToTable("StudentCourses");
    });
```

Comment: Can you update the answer giving details about composite foreign keys ? and deleting from only one table and not from the other foreign key table?

Comment: @BhushanFirake: You don't need to care about composite keys in this example. EF manages this automatically for the join table. To delete only a `Student`: `context.Students.Remove(student);` It will delete the student and the related entries in the join table. It doesn't delete any courses.