# Removing / Replacing referenced value using entity framework & code first

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

In a Code First model I have set up a DbSet<User> which contains a property List<Claim> Claims. 
When I call Claims.Clear() on a user and then call savechanges() on the repository the link is removed, but the Claim is still there in the database. It is no longer referenced by anything else. How do I go about removing it?

I get a similar issue trying to replace an entry in the claimlist with a similar claim that has the same unique ID. I am then unable to save since it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question answers yours on how to remove - specifically without forcing a load as well:

[Entity framework code first delete with cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520418/entity-framework-code-first-delete-with-cascade)

Comment: Matthew: It doesnt relate directly to my case. I ended up simply setting rep.Entry(existingUser.Claims[i]).State = EntityState.Deleted; before removing it from the parent's child list.