# DELETE statement conflicted in Database First

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework-6

Let's say I have a database with table A and table B. B has a foreign key to table A, which does not allow nulls. When I try to delete and entity of A I want all references in table B to be removed as well. I try to do this with the following code:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDatabaseContext(ConnectionString))
{
    var a= new A() { IdA= idA};
    ctx.A.Attach(a);
    ctx.A.Remove(a);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

This results in the following error message:

> Additional information: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_B_A". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase", table "dbo.B", column 'IdA'.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

I have tried a lot, from using Triggers in the database to defining the ON DELETE CASCADE, but Entity Framework does fail. What am I doing wrong?

Trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_DelA]
ON [dbo].[A]
FOR DELETE AS
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM B WHERE B.IdA = IdA;
  END
```

BTW: This is just an example. The actual database is larger and also contains intermediate tables for many to many relationships.

BR
Thomas

Comment: Can you provide reproducible example? Both cascade delete and instead of delete trigger on table A should work and it doesn't matter - will delete be called by EF or manually. What exactly have you tried to do on DB side?

Comment: I added the trigger code to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AFTER` (or `FOR` - they are synonyms) trigger are fired **after** triggering SQL statement. In your case this is too late, since deleting statement can't be completed due to foreign keys.

If you want to use trigger to handle cascade deletion - you have to use `instead of` trigger, and in this trigger first delete records from `B` table and then from `A` table.

So this could look like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_DelA]
ON [dbo].[A]
INSTEAD OF DELETE AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM B WHERE B.IdA in (select IdA from deleted)
    DELETE FROM A WHERE IdA in (select IdA from deleted)
END
```

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) for reference.

Comment: Oh I see. So there is no BEFORE but only an INSTEAD trigger? When I try to add this trigger I get the following message: Cannot alter INSTEAD OF DELETE or INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER 'trg_DelHarness' on table 'dbo.Harnesses'. This is  because the table has a FOREIGN KEY with cascading DELETE or UPDATE

Comment: I will try to remove the cascading from the foreign key

Comment: Now I could create the trigger

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. Now I have to apply these triggers to all my tables.

Answer (score 1):

Cascade your deletes.

Take a look at this: [Entity framework code first delete with cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520418/entity-framework-code-first-delete-with-cascade)

And this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295843(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: I am not using Code First but Model from Database. Does this also work?