# Deleting an a row with a foreign key (Entity Framework)

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework

If I have an object that has a foreign key to and I delete this object will it delete the object associated to it by the foreign key?  (I always thought the answer was no).

I am using entity framework and I am setting up a bunch of 1 to many relations for items.

Ie Company has many orders. Orders would have a foreign key to Company.  Deleting an order would not delete the corresponding Company correct? But Deleting the Company would delete the corresponding orders?

I know this is really an easy one but some internet postings have gotten me confused.

Comment: Cascading generally [only?] goes Parent->Child. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448702/cascading-deletes-with-entity-framework-related-entities-deleted-by-ef might be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no, When you delete a company you can do 2 things, remove the CompanyID of the Order or as you say delete the order. By Default it will just delete the Orders.