# Entity Framework does not cascade delete child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a parent and child entities. In the db, the relationship is set to `ON DELETE CASCADE'.

The EF code-first Fluent api mapping for the relationship is:

```
this.HasMany(t => t.Children)
    .WithOptional()
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

The code to delete an entity is:

```
public virtual void Delete(Parent entity)
{
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = dataContext.GetEntry(entity);
    if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
    {
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    else
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

When I try to delete the parent entity, I get the following exception:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

As cascade delete is already set correctly, doesn't EF automatically perform a cascade delete?

Or should I manually delete the children before deleting the parent entities?

**EDIT**

I added the following code to the above `Delete` method:

```
if (entity.Children != null)
{
    dataContext.Set<Child>().RemoveRange(entity.Children);
}
```

The children and parent records are deleted succesfully.

Is the above code really necessary? Shouldn't EF/SQL Server handle cascade delete?

Comment: Perhaps there is some other non-null FK that references `Children` entities?

Comment: Are 'ParentId' column has 'NULL' property in Your Database? Show Your 'Children' model code.

Comment: There are no non-null FK references and `ParentId` doesn't allow nulls in the `Children` table.

Comment: The children need to be loaded for the EF cascade to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448702/cascading-deletes-with-entity-framework-related-entities-deleted-by-ef