# Why must I access the related fields of a user before I can delete them in ASP.NET MVC EF app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

There is a ApplicationUser.  They can have multiple TfsAccounts and one TfsToken.  A TfsAccount can have multiple TrackedTasks.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<TfsAccount> TfsAccounts { get; set; }
    public virtual TfsToken TfsToken { get; set; }
}

public class TfsAccount
{
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TrackedTask> TrackedTasks { get; set; }
}

public class TrackedTask
{
    [ForeignKey("TfsAccountId")]
    public virtual TfsAccount TfsAccount { get; set; }

    public int TfsAccountId { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have a method to cancel a subscription for a user and delete them:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> CancelSubscription()
{
    var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    var tfsAccounts = currentUser.TfsAccounts;  <---REMOVE THESE
    var tfsToken = currentUser.TfsToken;        <---TWO LINES AND IT BREAKS

    var result = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(currentUser);  <---ON THIS LINE

    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("CancellationConfirmed");
}
```

Here is the error I get in the browser:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.TfsAccounts_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId". The conflict occurred in database "TfsTeamStatus", table "dbo.TfsAccounts", column 'ApplicationUserId'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Why do I have to access the related fields on the user before I can delete the user?  This works but feels super hacky.

Answer (score 0):

That's super hacky. Correct.
You need to set `on delete cascade` option to set for that.

If you are using *EF Designer*, then you can do that using [EF Designer as per these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448702/cascading-deletes-with-entity-framework-related-entities-deleted-by-ef#5448843)

> 1. Set Cascade on relation in EF designer. This instruct context that all
>      loaded related entities must be deleted prior to deletion of the
>      parent entity. If this doesn't happen EF will throw exception because
>      internal state will detect that loaded childs are not related to any
>      existing parent entity even the relation is required. I'm not sure if
>      this happens before execution of delete statement of the parent entity
>      or after but there is no difference. EF doesn't reload related
>      entities after executing modifications so it simply doesn't know about
>      cascade deletes triggered in the database.
> 2. Set ON CASCADE DELETE on
>      relation in database. This will instruct SQL to delete all related
>      records which were not loaded to context in the time of deleting the
>      parent.

If you are doing `code first approach`, you can do that using `Fluent API` as per [[Entity Framework (EF) Code First Cascade Delete for One-to-Zero-or-One relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487577/entity-framework-ef-code-first-cascade-delete-for-one-to-zero-or-one-relations])

> ```
> protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
> {
>    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
>       .HasOptional(a => a.UserDetail)
>       .WithOptionalDependent()
>       .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
> }
> ```

*Now, coming to your point, I am not sure why it works with the two lines when you access `TfsAccount` and `TfsToken`, but I guess `EF` might be setting `Modified` flag when you accessed it. So while doing `SaveChanges` it might be deleting those entities. - It's just a guess.*

Comment: Thanks @Paritosh, still trying to work through this.  When I add that, it seems to change the relationship to a one to zero or one relationship (an ApplicationUser can have zero or one TfsAccounts) when I need it to stay as a one to zero or many relationship.  Thoughts?  Been doing some googling but haven't found much on this type of relationship.